# Fail to deploy a lift web application to tomcat

Tags: scala, lift

I have created a war which includes the following jar files:
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
lift-actor_2.9.1-2.4-M4.jar
lift-common_2.9.1-2.4-M4.jar
lift-util_2.9.1-2.4-M4.jar
lift-webkit_2.9.1-2.4-M4.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
scala-library.jar

The web.xml file that i am using is:
[image]

Yet, when i try to deploy to tomcat 6 i get the following error:

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: For questions like this, the lift mailing list may be a better place. http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb